# boost::interprocess, get_free_memory()

Tags: c++, shared-memory, boost-interprocess

I use Boost::interprocess to create shared memory. But the reserved space is smaller than expected.

```
// Create new SHM
size_t memSize( vSimpleVtx.size()*sizeof(SimpleVtx)+
                vTriIndices.size()*sizeof(int)+
                vFeatureIndices.size()*sizeof(int)
                );
std::cout<<"D, memSize is "<<memSize<<std::endl;
mgshm=boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory(boost::interprocess::create_only, shmName,memSize);
std::size_t free_memory = mgshm.get_free_memory();
std::cout<<"Free memory="<<free_memory<<std::endl;
```

The above code prints:

```
D, memSize is 624
Free memory=400
```

When I reserve 674 bytes then 450 bytes are shown, so there is a constant offset of 224 bytes. Where did they get lost?

gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0

Comment: The allocator takes some overhead.  Do you really want `managed_shared_memory`, or would a simpler [`shared_memory_object`/`mapped_reagion`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.sharedmemory.shared_memory_a_simple_example) meet your needs?

Comment: Ah, I didn't expect that. That makes it hard to reserve just enough memory with managed shm. But you are right, a shared_memory_object is enough for the purpose. Thank you!